Different custom materials for each molecules in Molecular addon

as you can see, I'm trying to make a simple animation here. u can guess what :). so i used molecular addon to do this animation. now i want to make the material of the balls in each segment different color. how do i do that?
they are emitting a single sphere many times and i can only change the material of it now. i can make it random now. but that doesn't solve my problem. It would be easy if i can make it all mesh too. Does anyone know how to do that?

That is a third-party addon and not part of or built into Blender so questions about it are off-topic here. You'll have to ask the author There appears to be some information here and links to his Discord and X/Twitter feeds on the Github addon's download page.
